# Implementing EventoLog using C++

Tags: c++, windows-console

I'm trying to implement EventLog using C++ using this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2)

But on this line:

```
Console::WriteLine( "CreatingEventSource" );
```

Visual studio doesn't recognize the console object:

[image]

Any of you knows why Visual studio (2017) doesn't recognize the Console object?

Comment: Do you have an actual compile error, or just a problem with Intellisense?

Comment: In current state question makes no sense - you claim there is an error pn the line that not even shown in the code... Specifying what project type you picked would help a lot too. Side note: please check out [MCVE] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+fluff links to make your future questions better.

Comment: Also you probably need to add "c++-cli" tag as you are asking about managed C++ and not regular one.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you linked to uses `Console` as follows:

```
Console::WriteLine("Test");
```

You'll want to make sure your `#using` and `using` directives are complete as well.

Comment: even if I change to Console::WriteLine visual studio doesn't recognize the Console object. Do you know why ?

Comment: I expect you're missing one or both of `#using <System.dll>` and `using namespace System;`.

Comment: Yes,  #using <system.dll> using namespace System;
 using namespace System::Diagnostics;
 using namespace System::Threading;

Comment: What sort of project have you created?  Pretty sure you'll need it to be a CLR Console App.

Comment: I'm tying to create windows application but I want create log to keep track of errors.